# How to prevent deleting a term if used?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there any way to prevent deleting a taxonomy term if it used in any node ?

I have a `Taxonomy` that is used in `Field Collection` in my `Content Type` , I want to warn/prevent deletion of any `Term` in that `Taxonomy` if it is used in any node.

I checked `taxonomy_term_confirm_delete` it is where the confirmation message is formed,
I read from some posts about using

```
db_query("SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE tid = :aid", array(':aid' => $tid) )->fetchField()
```

to get the number of nodes a term is used in but this is not working in my case -maybe because the taxonomy is in field collection ?

Comment: If it's a field collection, you could query the `field_data_field_term_reference` table for that entity's term reference field instead.

Comment: For Drupal 8. [Prevent Term Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/prevent_term_delete) module is built to prevent the taxonomy term deletion when the taxonomy term is associated with nodes or entities using taxonomy term reference.

Comment: For D7 [Restrict Delete Used Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_rdut)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an [article](http://www.gbyte.co/blog/prevent-deletion-taxonomy-term-if-associated-node) tackling this problem.

In short, you have to use hook_form_alter on the form taxonomy_form_term and use the function [taxonomy_select_nodes()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7) to check if a node uses the term in question.

You can just copy the code from the article into your custom module (naming the 'mymodule_form_alter' accordingly to your module's name), flush the caches and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`taxonomy_select_nodes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7) function to achieve this.

> Return nodes attached to a term across all field instances.

```
taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC'))
```

Parameters

**$tid:** The term ID.

**$pager:** Boolean to indicate whether a pager should be used.

**$limit:** Integer. The maximum number of nodes to find. Set to FALSE for no limit.

**$order:** An array of fields and directions.

Comment: i am getting an empty array as a result eventhough my term is used in one node. the taxonomy is in a field collection, does that make any difference ?

Comment: Drupal 8 no longer has taxonomy_select_nodes so you'll want to load the nodes using entityQuery.